# use jq variable (from "as") to look up a key

Tags: jq

Given JSON like:

```
{"thing": ["hello", "bye"], "other": {"hello": "myval"}}
```

I want a jq expression which takes the first element of the array under "thing" and looks it up in "other". So I did:

```
jq '.thing[0] as $tofind | .other.$tofind'
```

but I get

```
jq: error: syntax error, unexpected '$', expecting FORMAT or QQSTRING_START (Unix shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 1:
.thing[0] as $tofind | .other.$tofind
jq: 1 compile error
```

I've tried a variety of other approaches:

```
echo '{"thing": ["hello", "bye"], "other": {"hello": "myval"}}' | jq '.thing[0] as $tofind | .other.($tofind)'
jq: error: syntax error, unexpected '(', expecting FORMAT or QQSTRING_START (Unix shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 1:
.thing[0] as $tofind | .other.($tofind)
jq: 1 compile error
echo '{"thing": ["hello", "bye"], "other": {"hello": "myval"}}' | jq '.thing[0] as $tofind | .other.[($tofind)]'
jq: error: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting FORMAT or QQSTRING_START (Unix shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 1:
.thing[0] as $tofind | .other.[($tofind)]
jq: 1 compile error
echo '{"thing": ["hello", "bye"], "other": {"hello": "myval"}}' | jq '.thing[0] as $tofind | .other.[$tofind]'
jq: error: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting FORMAT or QQSTRING_START (Unix shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 1:
.thing[0] as $tofind | .other.[$tofind]
jq: 1 compile error
echo '{"thing": ["hello", "bye"], "other": {"hello": "myval"}}' | jq '.thing[0] as $tofind | .other.["$tofind"]'
jq: error: syntax error, unexpected '[', expecting FORMAT or QQSTRING_START (Unix shell quoting issues?) at <top-level>, line 1:
.thing[0] as $tofind | .other.["$tofind"]
jq: 1 compile error
echo '{"thing": ["hello", "bye"], "other": {"hello": "myval"}}' | jq '.thing[0] as $tofind | .other."$tofind"'
null
echo '{"thing": ["hello", "bye"], "other": {"hello": "myval"}}' | jq '.thing[0] as $tofind | .other."($tofind)"'
null
```

I found a hacky workaround with `select` and `to_entries`, but I feel like there's got to be a decent way to do this that I'm missing.

Comment: `echo '{"thing": ["hello", "bye"], "other": {"hello": "myval"}}' | jq '.thing[0] as $tofind | .other.[$tofind]'` works fine here. On which shell did you run these commands?

Comment: @oguzismail I'm on bash (on OSX) and jq 1.6 — the problem seems to be doing ".other.[$tofind]" rather than just ".other[$tofind]" (no dot in the middle). Do you have some combination of shell and jq version that accepts the query with the dot in between?

Comment: It has nothing to do with the shell. I have `jq-1.6-104-ge74eab8` installed, and it accepts the query in my previous comment

Comment: Doesn't work for me pasting right into bash 3.2 with jq 1.6 — I get the jq compile error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.thing[0] as $tofind | .other[$tofind]
```

Comment: Please explain that how your answer will help to solve the problem, and just dont give code only answer without context

Comment: :facepalm: Yes, this works. The issue I was having was that I had a "." *and* square brackets. I accepted this as the answer instead of peak's since it is a bit more general (e.g. if I wanted to iterate over all the things in the thing array I could do that with this answer.)

Comment: it looks like you had the answer.  probably just thrashing a bit. i've been there :-)

Answer (score 1):

You could simply write:

```
jq '.other[.thing[0]]'
```